# Iterate through a list of tuple

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, nltk, porter-stemmer

i have a list of tuples:
tuple_list = [('remarkably','remark'),('prevented','prevent'),...]

I am trying to create a dictionary where the key is the stemmer and the value is the list of words with that stemmer.
How do I go about doing this?
this is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
 stem_dict = {}
    for index, tuple in tuple_list:
        if tuple == same_words:
            stem_dict += tuple
```

i am looking for an output similar to this:
output:{‘achiev’: [‘achieved’, ‘achieve’]
‘accident’: [‘accidentally’, ‘accidental’] … }

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output you desire?

Comment: also what is a stemmer?

Comment: Stemming is a term I read in SQL Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search?view=sql-server-ver15). Remarkably, Remarkable, etc are stems of remark. So, I am guessing the OP considers Remarkably, Prevented etc. as stemmers.